# Django Oauth calls

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0

I've got a site built in django that I need to make oauth2.0 requests to an external site to get the currently logged in user. Right now I'm just using a test token, however I have to actually register callbacks on my site now. How do I do this?

Comment: Is your site acting as an oauth2 client or provider?

Answer (score 0):

you must add oauth2 to the INSTALED_APPS list and add some settings constant to the settings.py of the project and append some urls on the main urls.py file of the project and ...
read the [django-oauth2](http://django-oauth2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) doumentations.